# Week Number Starting Monday in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using `Microsoft SQL Server` and am trying to extract the week number of the year but starting on Monday.

For example, between `2020-12-14 and 2020-12-20` that would be `Week 51`.

I have tried the following `datepart(week,categorydate)` this will start on Sunday, however, I want it to start on Monday.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: The manual is pretty hot on this stuff

Comment: can you specify the version of MySql? And, for week number do you mean which week in this year or the day of the week?

Comment: Datepart isn't mysql are you sure you tagged it correctly

Comment: @nbk - you are right I untagged it infact because I use Microsoft SQL Server, I have even updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sql server you have to set the start date first before `datepart`

```
-- Monday is first day of week
set datefirst 1;
select DATEPART(week,getdate()) as Week
```

Comment: this till give the weekday of the week not the Week number in the year

Comment: Without using "set datefirst": select datepart(iso_week, getdate())

ISO Week Number
You can also return the ISO week number from a date by using the iso_week argument. ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year.

Answer (score 2):

`WEEK(date,7)` will get you the week number starting from monday

MySQL WEEK() returns the week number for a given date.

The argument allows the user to specify whether the week starts on Sunday or Monday and whether the return value should be in the range from 0 to 53 or from 1 to 53. If no argument is included with the function, it returns the default week format.

Syntax:

```
WEEK(date[,mode]);
```

Mode    | First day of week |   Range   | Week 1 is the first week …

0 |  Sunday |   0-53 |  with a Sunday in this year

1   | Monday |  0-53 |  with more than 3 days this year

2   | Sunday |  1-53 |  with a Sunday in this year

3 | Monday |    1-53 |  with more than 3 days this year

4 | Sunday |    0-53 |  with more than 3 days this year

5 | Monday |    0-53    | with a Monday in this year

6   | Sunday |  1-53    | with more than 3 days this year

7   | Monday    | 1-53 |    with a Monday in this year

Comment: he tagged the rdms wrong

Comment: Question is about SQL SERVER. 'WEEK' is not a recognized OR built-in function name in SQL SERVER